# Node.js - changing the value of an exported integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file `A.js` where I have a module-level variable `activeCount`. I used module.exports to export it. I have a test file `testA.js` where I check the value of `activeCount`.

However it seems that the changes I make in `A.js` to `activeCount` aren't seen by `testA.js`. I think this is probably because when I change `activeCount`, it causes `module.exports.activeCount` and `activeCount` to point at different objects. Am I analyzing this correctly, and if so how do I change the value of `activeCount` without creating a new object?

A.js

```
var activeCount = 0;
...

function reset() {
    activeCount = 0;
}

function A() {
    ...
}
module.exports = A;
module.exports.activeCount = activeCount;
module.exports.reset = reset;

A.prototype.addFunction(...) {
    ...
    activeCount++;
    ...
}
```

testA.js

```
var A = require('A');

test('test1', function (assert) {
    var a = new A();
    a.addFunction(...);
    console.log(A.activeCount); // prints 0 instead of 1
});

test('test2', function (assert) {
    A.reset();
    var a = new A();
    a.addFunction(...);
    console.log(A.activeCount); // also prints 0 instead of 1
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Javascript, when you assign an integer (or any primitive - e.g. non-object), it is copied into the new variable.  Thus a change to the new variable does not influence the original variable.  Javascript does not have a true reference type for integers.

The usual work-around is to export an object (which is assigned by pointer) and then put the integer as a property on that object.  Then, changing the property on the object will be seen by everyone who has a reference to that object.

As it turns out, you are already exporting activeCount as a property of an object (since it is a property of `module.exports` in the `A.js` module.  So, you just need to change the "A" module to use it from there rather than use it's local copy.  There are a couple different ways to do that.  Here's one:

```
// A.js
function reset() {
    // change the exported variable
    module.exports.activeCount = 0;
}

function A() {
    ...
}
module.exports = A;
module.exports.activeCount = 0;
module.exports.reset = reset;

A.prototype.addFunction(...) {
    ...
    // change the exported variable
    module.exports.activeCount++;
    ...
}
```

Now, your testA.js module will work as expected.

---

Note, since you are doing `module.exports = A;` and functions are objects, you could also reference `activeCount` as a property of `A` while inside the `A` module and it would also solve the problem and give the desired result:

```
// A.js
function reset() {
    // change the exported variable
    A.activeCount = 0;
}

function A() {
    ...
}

// add properties to our constructor function so those properties
// are also exported
A.activeCount = 0;
A.reset = reset;
module.exports = A;

A.prototype.addFunction(...) {
    ...
    // change the exported variable
    module.exports.activeCount++;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The above goes for all primitives in JavaScript; Strings, Numbers & Booleans.

Comment: Yes i saw that, overall a good answer, nice and straight forward. Good way to walk readers though your thinking :-)